# Как создать 3Д ланшафт?

Tags: java

Пытался создать в СДК jMonkeyEngine, 3Д ландшафт, действовал по [этой инструкции](http://www.jmonkeyengine.ru/wiki/sdk/terrain_editor), но увы там старый СДК.

Не получилось, пишет ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было нажать правой кнопкой мыши  на файл `newScene.j3o` выбрать  `Edit in SceneComposer`
после снизу с лева нажать на `Scene Root` после левой кнопкой выбрать `Add Spatial...` -> `Node`

нажать на `Node` выбрать `Edit Terrain` после нажать на `Add Terrain`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]